# Python3 update locals() dict with **kwargs bad idea?

Tags: python

Just wanted to know if this is a bad convention (which I am assuming is the case):

```py
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    locals().update(kwargs)
    try:
        print(args, kwargs, a)
    except NameError:
        print('"a" is not defined')
```

Why do this?

Suppose you have a python `dict` which serves as a config. This config may be lengthy and as a lazy programmer you do not want to have an enormous `def` statement naming the `kwargs`, you also do not necessarily always want to write `kwargs["my_var"]` or inside the function `def` write `my_var = kwargs["my_var"]`.

Again I think this is not the best way to handle it. I am just curious if there might be another solution.

Comment: You can't alter function locals, because changes to the `locals()` dictionary *are not reflected back*.

Comment: So it's not a bad idea, nor is it a good idea, because *it doesn't do anything to anything other than the dictionary `locals()` returned*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in my console if I run `foo(a=1)` it prints if I run `foo(1,2,3)` it throws the error suggesting that the `locals()` dict is actually updated...

Comment: Putting configuration in a dictionary is great. You don't need to put all of those key-value pairs into local variables, just use the dictionary directly.

Comment: Local names in functions are determined at compile time, and CPython uses an array to store them. The dictionary `locals()` returns is created by copying the values from the array to a dictionary together with the local variable names stored in the code object to form the keys. You can't add more locals by writing to `locals()`. Sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok :) thank you for your guidence